# trying to convert rgb value to hex

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

i got the output as
rgb(250, 219, 233) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box

i want to convert this to hex value.

```
List<WebElement> datesOfMonths = driver.findElements(
         By.xpath("//a[@class=\"ui-state-default\"]"));
System.out.println(datesOfMonths.size());
for (int i = 0; i < datesOfMonths.size(); i++) {
    String backgroundValue = datesOfMonths.get(i).getCssValue("background");
    if (backgroundValue.contains("250") || backgroundValue.contains("71")
            || backgroundValue.contains("134") || backgroundValue.contains("248")) {
        System.out.println(backgroundValue);
    } else  {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have...a question? Are you getting a specific error message? Unexpected behavior (describe)?

Answer (score -1):

### rgb convert hex

```java
public class Rgb2Hex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = 255;
        int g = 255;
        int b = 255;
        String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
        System.out.println(hex);
    }
}
```